# ASP.NET Core pass int value from ajax to View

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core

In ASP.NET Core I am trying to pass a value from `ajax` to `view`, I have an `action` that passes an `int` 
value to an `ajax` call, and from there, `ajax` tells my `view` to blink or not. Here is the `controller`

```
public ActionResult GetCounselingCount()
{
        var result = 0;
        try
        {
            var Counseling = _context.TableName.Where(f => f.FolderStatusId == 12)
               .Where(f => f.IsActive == true).Count();

            if (Counseling != 0)
            {
                result = Counseling;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        return Json(result);
}
```

`result` is passed to my `ajax` call

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: window.location.origin + "/ControllerName/GetCounselingCount",
    success: function (result) {
        if (result != 0) {
            $('#phaSection').addClass("blinking");
        }
        else {
            if ($('#phaSection').hasClass("blinking")) {
                $('#phaSection').removeClass("blinking");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This works fine when I pass `<li id="phaSection">` to my `view`,

```
<li id="phaSection" class="nav-item @((ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString() == "ControllerName") && (ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString() == "Counseling") ? "active" : "")">
    <a class="nav-link" asp-controller="ControllerName" asp-action="Counseling">
        <i class="fas fa-book-reader"></i>
        <span>Counseling</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

This causes `<span>Counseling</span>` to blink as expected, however my question is how can I pass the `int` value `result` from my `ajax` to be displayed in my `view`? Instead of my view `<span>Counseling</span>`, I want it to be

`<span>Counseling + "value"</span>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can identify the `<span>` within your current target element and set its text:

```
$('#phaSection span').text('Counseling + ' + result);
```

Or give the `<span>` its own `id`:

```
<span id="someID">Counseling</span>
```

And target that directly like you do for the containing element:

```
$('#someID').text('Counseling + ' + result);
```

Either way, what you're looking to do is not "pass an int to a view" but rather just set the text of an element.